# how to make minted to do bold keywords?

Tags: latex, beamer

I would like to have bold font for minted rendered source code like in minted package manual. Currently keywords are in usual font.

```latex
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}
\definecolor{lightlightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}
{cpp}
  // class A
  class A {
    int boo;
  };
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there is no bold tt family in the Computer Modern Typewriter font. Try `lmodern` instead:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{cpp}
  // class A
  class A {
    int boo;
  };
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See [Using \ttfamily with \bfseries (or how to enable bold in fixed-width font)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33039/using-ttfamily-with-bfseries-or-how-to-enable-bold-in-fixed-width-font) for details.

Comment: Adding \usepackage[english,russian]{babel} breaks it again... What can be done in this case?

Comment: @Alexander Try to add `\selectlanguage{english}` before the minted environment.